# Adicionar dias ao prazo de entrega no Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Como posso adicionar 20 dias ao prazo de entrega no Woocommerce quando o produto estiver com estoque 0 e habilitado para encomendas?

Comment: não cheguei a configurar mas acho que este pluggin pode te ajudar. Acredito que tenha no módulo um range possível de seleção, e poderá escolha o prazo. Veja se te ajuda e nos informe na sequencia. Opção 1 - https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-order-delivery/
Opção 2 - https://wordpress.org/plugins/order-delivery-date-for-woocommerce

Answer (score 1):

Olá!
Você está usando algum plugin de entregas, tipo correios?
Um plugin legal é o do Claudio Sanches..
O caminho no seu painel (após o plugin instalado) é:
WOOCOMMERCE>
CONFIGURAÇÕES>
ENTREGA>
CORREIOS>
No campo ˜dias adicionais" preencha com "20" e salve.

LINK DO PLUGIN> https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-correios/

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, já utilizo esse plugin. Porém dessa forma vou adicionar 20 dias a todos os pedidos. Preciso que esse prazo seja adicionado apenas quando o estoque for 0.